# Undefined variable in laravel when i try to send mail

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a email for various persons in my site, but I receive from Laravel:

> Undefined variable: usuariosAnjos

This is my function:

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request){


        $data = array(
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'lng' => $request->lng,
            'foto' => $request->foto
        );

        $usuariosAnjos = User::select('email')->where('usuario_anjo', 1)->get();



    for($i=0; $i < count($usuariosAnjos); $i++){
        Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message){
            $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'Ei, tem um pet precisando da sua ajuda!');
            $message->to($usuariosAnjos[$i][$email]);
        });
    }
    return response()->json("Email enviado com sucesso", 201);
}
```

If I put on `response()->json($usuariosAnjos,201)`, I receive my array.

Why am I getting the undefined variable `#usuariosAnjos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use ($usuariosAnjos, $i) {
            $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'Ei, tem um pet precisando da sua ajuda!');
            $message->to($usuariosAnjos[$i][$email]);
        });
```

Basically, when you're using closure and using external variables, you have to use `use` that variable along the closure.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a closure function like the third parameter

```
Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message){ .... });
```

That function will run in other place in the code where that variables are not declared or not exist because that is other scope.

You need always pass the variables that it will use in the future. For this you can use "use" php statment

```
 Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use ($usuariosAnjos,$i){ .... });
```

And in this case the correct way maybe it pass the email adresss directly

```
foreach($usuariosAnjos as $user){
        $email = $user->email;
        Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
            $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'Ei, tem um pet precisando da sua ajuda!');
            $message->to($email);
        });
    }
```

Try this and let know how it works... :)